# Template multiple inheritance ambigious symbol error

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, crtp

i got a real problem, which can be summarized like this:

```
template <typename BaseType>
class TemplateClass
{
public:
    template <typename BaseTypee, unsigned PrefixID>
    static void deleteType(unsigned int ObjID)
    {

    }
};

class ParentClass:
    public TemplateClass<ParentClass>
{
};

class ChildClass:
      public ParentClass, public TemplateClass<ChildClass>
{   
    using TemplateClass<ChildClass>::deleteType; //Ambigious Symbol Compiler-Error

};
```

I call the function `deleteType` like this:

```
TemplateClass<ChildClass>::deleteType<ChildClass, ChildType>(ChildType);
```

I want to call the function *deleteType* in the *ChildClass* Class, but without any declaration the function will be called in *ParentClass*.

How can i get rid of the ambigious symbol error in the using-phrase? Can achieve my task with a different approach?

FYI: Originally, i tried calling the function with (nothing changes)

```
ChildClass::deleteType<ChildClass, ChildType>(ChildType);
```

funny thing: it still compiles although has a red underline. If i debug, the Template will be still called in *ParentClass*, at compilation is no warning nor error thrown..

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `ChildClass::TemplateClass<ChildClass>::deleteType<ChildClass, ChildType>(ChildType);`

Comment: You have two completely different, unrelated template parameters both named `BaseType` that your `deleteType` depends on. One is a parameter of `TemplateClass` and the other is a parameter of `deleteType`. In total, `deleteType` depends on three template parameters, one of them is named the same as, and shadowed by, the other. You probably don't want that.

Comment: Please provide compilable code, **expected output** and **actual output** (add output statements to relevant functions). It is entirely unclear what you expect your code to do. If you say "I want it to print X but it prints Y instead" there's no wiggle room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `using` statement in a `public:` section :

```
template <typename BaseType>
class TemplateClass
{
public:
    template <typename BaseTypee, unsigned PrefixID>
    static void deleteType(unsigned int ObjID)
    {
    }
};

class ParentClass:
    public TemplateClass<ParentClass>
{
};

class ChildClass:
      public ParentClass, public TemplateClass<ChildClass>
{   
public:
    using TemplateClass<ChildClass>::deleteType;
};

int main() {
    ChildClass::deleteType<void, 0>(0);
}
```

Comment: TemplateClass will be still red underlined with the same error: *Ambigious Symbol 'TemplateClass<ChildClass>::deleteType'*, funny thing: it still compiles although has a red underline. If i debug, the Template will be still called in *ParentClass* @Johan Boule

Comment: What compiler/IDE do you use ?

Comment: It did function correctly now, i had some issues with destructors in my deep implementation. Your Solution is correct :-) greetings